# how to mount a file share in azure service fabric

Tags: c#, file, azure-storage, azure-service-fabric, smb

I need to access files using standard file API in a Service Fabric service. My application read from files and write to files that are stored in a File Share; each node process a different part of the data.

I'm using the "SetupEntryPoint" to run a batch file with a "net use" command to mount a local drive to my file share but it fails (both on my local machine and when deployed on Azure). I'm referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-model) article. The same batch runs well on a regular virtual machine but fails on a Fabric node.

I would like an example of how this can be achieved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [this project](https://github.com/sandrinodimattia/RedDog/tree/master/src/RedDog.Storage/Files) for a while to map drives in code and it works well on service fabric.  You should be able to put this in your code before your file access calls.