# Service fabric accessing unc drive to store a file. is it possible?

Tags: c#, azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric, unc

I have an service (.net core) running in Service fabric (self-hosted). I tried searching on the internet to find some resources to help me construct a possible solution but failed to get good reliable sources so far.

I have two possible ideas in my mind:
1) Treat the unc drive like any other drive and use StreamReader and Streamwriter.

2) Mount the files as local drives (somehow) and use StreamReader and Streamwrier based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365071/how-to-mount-a-file-share-in-azure-service-fabric)

I don't understand the second one completely so far.

Will it be able to access an unc drive to store and retrieve files? 
How would I go about doing that?

Comment: To add context: We were using azure file share using the SDK until the software on the other end for some reason could not connect with it and they had to go with a more traditional network drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easiest to mount the unc drive as a local drive.

You can [script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows#persisting-azure-file-share-credentials-in-windows) a mount to the file share. Put the credentials into configuration.
Run the script as a [setup entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-run-script-at-service-startup) of the service.
Make sure the script runs [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

Sample script:

```
$resourceGroupName = "<your-resource-group-name>"
$storageAccountName = "<your-storage-account-name>"
$fileShareName = "<your-file-share-name>"

# These commands require you to be logged into your Azure account, run Login-AzAccount if you haven't
# already logged in.
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName
$storageAccountKeys = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName
$fileShare = Get-AzStorageShare -Context $storageAccount.Context | Where-Object { 
    $_.Name -eq $fileShareName -and $_.IsSnapshot -eq $false
}

if ($fileShare -eq $null) {
    throw [System.Exception]::new("Azure file share not found")
}

# The value given to the root parameter of the New-PSDrive cmdlet is the host address for the storage account, 
# <storage-account>.file.core.windows.net for Azure Public Regions. $fileShare.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.Host is 
# used because non-Public Azure regions, such as sovereign clouds or Azure Stack deployments, will have different 
# hosts for Azure file shares (and other storage resources).
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $storageAccountKeys[0].Value -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "AZURE\$($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)", $password
New-PSDrive -Name <desired-drive-letter> -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\$($fileShare.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.Host)\$($fileShare.Name)" -Credential $credential -Persist
```

From that moment, you can use the drive any way you see fit. For example, by using `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` and {desired-drive-letter}.